# Android: Custom font works for TextView, not for Button

Tags: android, button, kotlin, textview, custom-font

I cannot get a Button to use my custom font.
It works fine with a TextView, not with a Button (which is a subclass of TextView).

I am using Android Studio 3.1.2 with minSdkVersion 26 and Kotlin.

*res/font/font.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/my-custom-font" />
</font-family>
```

*res/layout/fragment.xml*

```
...
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"
    android:minWidth="30dp"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/my-custom-font"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="a" />
...
```

The above works. Replace TextView with Button and it stops working.

Edit: I want to use a custom font to hold the icons for our Buttons, instead of using images and ImageButtons.  We find a custom font is easier to manage than images.

Comment: Isn't Button bold by default? you don't provide a bold style with your font

Comment: @SamuelEminet According to the [Fonts documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) I can only set `fontStyle` to `normal` or `italic`

Comment: To add a bold style add a font with a weight around 700 `android:fontWeight="700"`

Comment: Thanks @SamuelEminet but I am not trying to make it bold, just to use my custom font.  If I use the standard font for a Button it displays it with normal weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style to your button:

Create a new style under `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="main_button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my-custom-font</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

enter whatever values you want. Make sure to include the `fontFamily:`

Then on your button, add the style:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/id"
    style="@style/main_button" />
```

Comment: Plus your response gave me a hint: if I just add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to my button it does work.
I guess Buttons default to using all caps, and I have only mapped lower case characters so far.
So in summary: although using a style works and could be useful to specify attributes once for many buttons, custom fonts do work for buttons.

Comment: @FabioKatz Perfect! I like using styles cause there is less copying and pasting then when reusing the same style! I'm glad it helped you

Answer (score -1):

Use `app:fontFamily="@font/my-custom-font"` in your style, not `android:fontFamily="@font/my-custom-font"`